# Sending AMQP message to Service Bus Topic with Azure Logic Apps is possible?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have logic apps with "Send message" to Service Bus Topic.

Is it possible to send message in AMQP protocol instead of default Service Bus protocol?

**Update 2020-06-19**
It doesn't matter so much if the message is sent using SBMP or AMQP. What matters more is how it was serialized. Since LogicApp is using the legacy (track 0) SDK with `BrokerdMessage` the message not sent and recieved with the same serialization. Either you should see if you can send a message from the LogicApp using a `Stream` of byte array or on the receiving end use an extension method provided by the .NET Standard SDK (track 1) to access body that needs to be deserialized from the legacy SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The SBMP protocol you're referring to belongs to the oldest (legacy) version of the .NET SDK, `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` NuGet package. It also supports AMQP as a [`TransportMode` mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.transporttype?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-legacy). I would recommend to rather use the current package, `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` which is only using AMQP.

I've put together a [post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/the-future-of-asb-dotnet-sdk) describing some of the differences between these packages and the preview package that is currently being developed.

Comment: What is default protocol used if I send message from Logic Apps or Azure Functions? Am I already using AMQP or should it be configured for it?

Comment: Depends on the version. For example, Functions v3 will use the version of ASB SDK that only by default (and only) uses AMQP.

Comment: How I can check with protocol is used with Logic Apps?

Comment: That would be a [LogicsApp Service Bus connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/) information. From a quick analysis, it looks like the connector could be still on the Track 0 SDK (legacy) and that would explain why SBMP would be used to begin with. I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/BusinessApplicationPlatform-Connectors-public/issues/133) asking for clarification.

Comment: It has been confirmed that the connector is using the older version of the SDK. I've updated the answer to unblock you and pointed out what a potential solution can be. Cheers.